# Change colour of zoomed Tmux pane

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I'm using iTerm2 and Tmux.

I would like to change the background colour of a Tmux pane but only when zoomed. I would then like it to change back to its original colour when unzoomed. I know there is a window_zoomed_flag and am wondering if I can use this in a if-shell statement or somewhere else to get the desired effect?

I have also tried iterations similar to the following without success...

```
set -g window-active-style 'fg=white,#{?window_zoomed_flag,#[bg=black],#[bg=color235]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea but you will need to do this either in your key binding to zoom the pane or perhaps with the window-layout-changed hook (I think it is fired when zooming). For example the key binding could be:

```
bind z resizep -Z \; if -F '#{window_zoomed_flag}' 'selectp -P bg=red' 'selectp -P bg=green'
```